# Word order in english (adverbial modifier of place)

Tags: word-order

Could you tell me what’s wrong in this phrase:

"In this database, there are failed copies of the file."

Is it grammatically correct to write "In this database" at the beggining of a sentence?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, of course.

Answer (score 2):

You can keep the original-

- In this database there are failed copies of the file.

  In this database, there are failed copies of the file.

> or can rephrase it to-
>
> - The failed copies of the file are in this database.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's fine. Maybe you can drop that comma if you decide to say: "There are failed copies of the file in this database." Otherwise, I believe it's grammatically correct.

Comment: You can even drop the comma while retaining the original word order.